# java.io.FileNotFoundException via Uploading a file with a filename with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, java-8

I am having an uploading a file with- filename with resttemplate my code below;

my code below;

```
String filePath = "/C:/../../promoCode/" + fileName + ".txt";

    File targetFile = new File(filePath);

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(targetFile);
    BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(writer);
    buffer.write(generatedVoucherText);

    String bucketName = "promocodes";

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> fileMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition
            .builder("form-data")
            .name("file")
            .filename(fileName)
            .build();
    fileMap.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString());

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(targetFile);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

   String someByteArray = bufferedReader.readLine();

    HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(someByteArray.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), fileMap);


    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("file", requestEntity);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> httpEntity =
            new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

    minioService.postMinio2(httpEntity, bucketName);
    buffer.close();
```

I do not know why I am having I/O exception.

FullStackTrace
Exception log detail occured: I/O error on POST request for "http://sth-sth.apps.mbt.sth.local promocodes": class path resource [C:/../../promoCode/ABF.txt] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [C:/../../promoCode/ABF.txt] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist, class: class org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException

Thank you

Comment: Add the full exception stack trace to your question.

Comment: Hello I have edited